# using output template error via youtube-dl

Tags: download, terminal, ubuntu-14.04, youtube-dl

I admit, I'm new to Linux, but I pieced together the following in the Ubuntu terminal to download all of the videos from a YouTube channel:

youtube-dl -o "/media/ubuntu/3A3A9F353A9EED5F/%(uploader)s/%(autonumber)s.%(title)s.%(ext)s" --download-archive ~/.mydownloads  -citw ytuser:DirectFix

However, I keep getting this error:

**youtube-dl: error: using output template conflicts with using title, video ID or auto number**

What do I need to do so I can download the files straight to a separate internal drive, rename the files, and keep track of the videos I've already downloaded?

Answer (score 6):

Your options [`-citw` do not make any sense](https://github.com/rg3/youtube-dl/blob/master/README.md#do-i-always-have-to-pass--citw). Simply remove them (maybe leave `-i`) and the download will work.

In detail:

- `-c` forces youtube-dl to always resume downloads. By default, youtube-dl does already resume downloads. At best, this option is superfluous. At worst, you may be forcing youtube-dl to resume a download in another quality, which will result in a broken video file.
- `-i` makes youtube-dl continue if it cannot download a video from the playlist. Unlike the other options, it is regularly useful. Be aware that you may miss errors though, if you need a complete download.
- `-t` is the equivalent of `-o "%(title)s-%(id)s.%(ext)s"`. As such, it is causing the immediate error at hand, since you are passing in two different output templates and youtube-dl doesn't know which one to pick.
- `-w` forces youtube-dl to never overwrite an existing file. This is useful for metadata files, which you don't use in the first place. Even then, most users will want the updated information.